# What's the way to store the connection of a computer with server side script without using sockets

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

I was wondering if there is any way by which i can store the connection of a client script ( say flash as3 script ) with a server side file (php). So that at times, i can revoke that connection from server side script and connect back to the same computer ? 
I am not talking about socket connection. But via simple http connection. Is this possible at all ? Or not allowed due to security issues ?

Comment: why was this voted to be closed it seems like a legit question?

Comment: HTTP is a protocol that is typically transported over a TCP/IP Socket connection. I think you need to read some more and understand how networking works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, when plugins like Flash or features like web sockets aren't available, XHR long-polling is what is used for situations like this. Long-polling involves having the client make a server request and having the server not respond right away. By holding onto the request, the server keeps the connection alive, and can then wait until it has something to actually tell the client before it responds. Once the client gets a response, it immediately makes another request, so the server has another connection to use at will.

However, since you're using Flash, you can take advantage of [Flash Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html) to make a persistent connection. Flash Socket is actually a built-in fallback for frameworks built for client-server connections, like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) or [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

Answer (score 0):

The server to my knowledge can not instantiate a connection to the client just like you side it is a security issue and will be blocked.

Comment: But how a value is returned by a server then. Say i use a client side script to send a value. I also can add a listener to know what happened to my sent values. In this case there is something happening similar as if the server knows about the address and thus returns it back to the particular script file on a particular computer.